# Finding absorption coefficient of boron doped silicon

Tags: electromagnetism, infrared-radiation

I want to find absorption coefficient of boron doped silicon film with 0.08mm height but the curve i found is of  2mm. According to beer law, coefficient is inverse ly proportional problem is  I think reflection and transmission also change with depth. It is using IR wavees

Comment: https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.72.621

Comment: @hft thanks, any document on IR waves, near or far IR?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4877123/